# Possible Memory Leak When Creating Bitmaps

Tags: c#, winforms

Every tick of timer I'd like to check the received data: `"000000000"` and if any of these bits are set to `1` then change picturebox. This part of code is working - but I think I have a memory leak problem (memory used by program is increasing drastically). How to resolve this problem?

```
 private void RefreshingTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
       if (ReceivedDataTextBox.Text[i - 1].ToString() == "1")
          ((PictureBox)this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()]).Image = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\green.png");
       else ((PictureBox)this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()]).Image = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\red.png");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is not possible for the loop you provided to be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to dispose of the old image (`this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()]).Image`) before assigning it to a new one

```
private Bitmap _greenBitmap = new Bitmap(@"Logos\green.png"); 
private Bitmap _redBitmap = new Bitmap(@"Logos\red.png");

private void RefreshingTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
   {
       PictureBox p = 
          (PictureBox)this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()];
       if(p != null && p.Image != null)
       {  
          p.Image.Dispose();
       }

       bool is_one = (ReceivedDataTextBox.Text[i - 1].ToString() == "1");
       if(p != null)
       {
          p.Image = (is_one) ? _greenBitmap : _redBitmap;
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create always a new image.
Try to pre-create your image and only set it to the control.

```
private Bitmap greenBitmap = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\green.png"); 
private Bitmap redBitmap = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\red.png")

private void RefreshingTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) 
            { 
                if (ReceivedDataTextBox.Text[i - 1].ToString() == "1") 
                    ((PictureBox)this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()]).Image = greenBitmap; 
                else ((PictureBox)this.tabPage1.Controls["pictureBox_DO" + i.ToString()]).Image = redBitmap; 
            } 
        }
```